# RestTemplate is giving org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, http, https

I am trying to **POST** a payload with almost 4-5 MB of data through **RestTemplate**. Some of the request are passing but some of the requests are not even going to API gateway with this error

> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting
> for connection from pool

Here is the rest template implementation I am using.

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateHelper {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public RestTemplateHelper() {
}
private <X, Y> Y post(final String url, final String accessToken, final MediaType mediaType, final X requestBody, final Class<Y> responseType, final Map<String, String> extraHeaders, HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter, RestTemplate restTemplateFromParam) {
        HttpHeaders headers = this.getHeaders(accessToken, mediaType, extraHeaders);
        HttpEntity<X> httpEntity = new HttpEntity(requestBody, headers);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity;
        NonRetriableException nonRetriableException;
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplateToUse = this.restTemplate;
            if (Objects.nonNull(httpMessageConverter)) {
                restTemplateToUse = Objects.nonNull(restTemplateFromParam) ? restTemplateFromParam : restTemplateToUse;
                restTemplateToUse.getMessageConverters().add(0, httpMessageConverter);
            }

            responseEntity = restTemplateToUse.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, responseType, new Object[0]);
        } catch (ResourceAccessException var14) {
            nonRetriableException = new NonRetriableException(var14);
            nonRetriableException.setRootException(var14);
            throw nonRetriableException;
        } catch (RestClientResponseException var15) {
            nonRetriableException = new NonRetriableException(var15);
            nonRetriableException.setRawStatusCode(var15.getRawStatusCode());
            nonRetriableException.setStatusText(var15.getStatusText());
            nonRetriableException.setResponseBody(var15.getResponseBodyAsString());
            nonRetriableException.setResponseHeaders(var15.getResponseHeaders());
            nonRetriableException.setRootException(var15);
            throw nonRetriableException;
        } catch (Exception var16) {
            throw new NonRetriableException(var16);
        }

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong and dangerous. You have 1 instanceof the `RestTemplate` and keep adding/changing `HttpMessageConverters` this is plain wrong. If you have multiple concurrent requests this will start to break down.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for this. Can you please explain me the resolution. It would be very helpful if you do that because I am stuck at this place for very long time. One more thing in my case HttpMessageConverters is always null then also I am facing the issue

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please help me here

Comment: Remove the messing around with the http converters. Don't modify a `RestTEmplate` after its construction.